# convert string with substrings into multiple strings

Tags: r, string

I want ot convert my slash-separated strings into separate strings with quotes. Now, by strings is a long string where the substrings are separated by slash.

in

```
[1] "RPS3A/RPL9/RPS25"
```

out

```
[1] "RPS3A" "RPL9"  "RPS25"
```

Comment: maybe this: strsplit(in, "/+")

Comment: The `+` doesn't add any value to the split, unless you have `//`. at which point it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_split()` function from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_split("RPS3A/RPL9/RPS25", "/")
```

`unlist()` the prior output afterwards if type cast required.